# I do not know where the "Missing number" is

Tags: compilation-error

I've made what I thought was an exceedingly simple command, but the compiler yells at me that there is a "Missing number".  If I skip the error then everything compiles and produces the image I want. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is missing. MWE below.  I'm on an updated MikTex install:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand\filleddot{{\leavevmode\put(0,2){\circle*{5.0pt}}}}
    
\begin{document}
    \filleddot
\end{document}
```

Thank you all ahead of time. This site is a ridiculously valuable resource.

Comment: I get no error, show your log file.

Comment: I get the error with TeX Live 2019 and LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5, but not with later releases of LaTeX.

Comment: ...so, update your distribution and try again.

Comment: This is what happens when you update on one machine, but not the other!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `\circle*` used to be just a number, not a dimension.

Indeed, I get the error when trying LaTeX released 2020-02-02 or earlier, but not with more recent releases (on or after 2020-10-01).

If you can't update your TeX distribution (but you should), use just a number, which denotes a multiple of `\unitlength` (default value 1pt).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\filleddot{{\leavevmode\put(0,2){\circle*{5}}}}
    
\begin{document}

    \filleddot

\end{document}
```

Please, avoid `minimal` for examples: the class is not meant for such usage.

Comment: I just used minimal for this MWE.  I'm using book.